# Display a website using cocos2d

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview, cocos2d-iphone

I need to load a website in a cocos 2d game.

For example,when a ccmenu button is clicked,i need to replace a scene where it must load an particular website.

Any ideas please,thanks.

Comment: Not sure what you want to know? Add the UIWebView to cocos2d view and refer to the reference (see loadRequest for the simplest way): http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to get game data from a server, correct?  In that case, you probably aren't going to want to load an HTML page.  Instead, come up with some a method of storing pertinent game data in a more appropriate file format.  I can't say for sure because I don't know anything about your game, but saving your game data as XML might work well.  Then, when you need to update the game with data from your sever, use an `NSURLRequest` or similar to download the XML file, which you can then parse as you see fit.

Comment: No..i just want to load an website ...for example a chat page

Comment: Still, its going to be more efficient and look/respond better if you just query the server for data that you in turn use to populate a native interface.

Answer (score 0):

Look into CCHttpRequest or CCHttpClient.